# How to write a SQLite

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have a database with two tables , First one contains 2 columns: `group_ID , group_name` . And the second one : `ID, Word, Definition , word_group_id` .

This is the prototype of the function which I am going to write

> WordContainer [] findWordsByGroupId(int id);

and this is the WordContainer class:

> public class WordContainer {
>       String word;
>       String definition;
>       int id  = -1;

```
public WordContainer (int id , String word ,String definition){
    this.id = id;
    this.word = word;
    this.definition = definition;
}
public void setWord (String word){
    this.word = word;
}
public void setDefinition (String definition){
    this.definition = definition;
}
public String getWord (){
    return this.word;
}
public String getDefinition (){
    return this.definition;
}
```

}

So the question is , How to write a SQLite query which will find all the rows (or ids of those rows)which have the given group_id ;

Comment: use google, search SO there are tons of tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be easy to find onthe internet

```
"SELECT * FROM MyTableName WHERE group_id = '12'"
```

To get an arraylist

```
public ArrayList<YourObject> getYourObjects(){
    ArrayList<YourObject> yourObject= new ArrayList<YourObject>();

    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("YOUR QUERY",new String [] {});
    for(int i = 0; i<cur.getCount(); i++){
        cur.moveToPosition(i);      
        String string.setTimeInMillis(cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("YOUR_COLLUMN_NAME")));     
        yourObject.add(new YourObject());
    }
    cur.close();
    db.close();

    return workObjects;
}
```

Comment: I know this query , the problem is to save them as an array

Comment: thats not what you are asking! read some info about cursors and sqlite

Comment: Check the answere again

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<WordContainer> findWordsByGroupId(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<WordContainer> customList = new ArrayList<WordContainer>();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, null,
                group_ID + "=?", new String[]{id}, null, null, null);
        int count = 0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            WordContainer wordContainer= new WordContainer(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1));
            customList.add(listClass);

        }

        return customList;
    }
```

I have used `ArrayList` here but you can use `String Array`.